# dpkg dependency problems: Package python3 is not configured yet

Tags: apt, 22.04, dpkg, dependencies, python3

I had to perform a reboot recently, and running `sudo apt upgrade` has resulted in dependency problems ever since:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libapparmor1 libargon2-1 libcryptsetup12 libdevmapper1.02.1 libip4tc2 libjson-c5 libkmod2 systemd
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3 (3.10.6-1~22.04) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
dpkg-query: package 'ibus-table' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus-table
error running python rtupdate hook ibus-table
dpkg-query: package 'ibus' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus
error running python rtupdate hook ibus
dpkg-query: package 'python3-uno' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of python3-uno
error running python rtupdate hook python3-uno
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer-common
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer-common
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Setting up systemd (249.11-0ubuntu3.9) ...
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-wheel:
 python3-wheel depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-wheel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on python3 (= 3.10.6-1~22.04); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pip:
 python3-pip depends on python3-wheel; however:
  Package python3-wheel is not configured yet.
 python3-pip depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-release:
 lsb-release depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-release (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-lib2to3:
 python3-lib2to3 depends on python3:any (>= 3.10.5-0~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-lib2to3 depends on python3:any (<< 3.12); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-lib2to3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pkg-resources:
 python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pkg-resources (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distutils:
 python3-distutils depends on python3:any (>= 3.10.5-0~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-distutils depends on python3:any (<< 3.12); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-distutils depends on python3-lib2to3 (= 3.10.6-1~22.04); however:
  Package python3-lib2to3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-setuptools:
 python3-setuptools depends on python3-pkg-resources (= 59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1); however:
  Package python3-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
 python3-setuptools depends on python3-distutils; however:
  Package python3-distutils is not configured yet.
 python3-setuptools depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-setuptools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distro:
 python3-distro depends on lsb-release; however:
  Package lsb-release is not configured yet.
 python3-distro depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip-data:
 hplip-data depends on python3-distro; however:
  Package python3-distro is not configured yet.
 hplip-data depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

  Package lsb-release is not configured yet.
 python3-distro depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip-data:
 hplip-data depends on python3-distro; however:
  Package python3-distro is not configured yet.
 hplip-data depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

  Package lsb-release is not configured yet.
 python3-distro depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip-data:
 hplip-data depends on python3-distro; however:
  Package python3-distro is not configured yet.
 hplip-data depends on python3:any; however:
  Package lsb-release is not configured yet.
 python3-distro depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip-data:
 hplip-data depends on python3-distro; however:
  Package python3-distro is not configured yet.
 hplip-data depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package hplip-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-all:
 python3-all depends on python3 (= 3.10.6-1~22.04); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-all depends on python3-distutils (>= 3.10.6-1~); however:
  Package python3-distutils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 systemd
  Package lsb-release is not configured yet.
 python3-distro depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip-data:
 hplip-data depends on python3-distro; however:
  Package python3-distro is not configured yet.
 hplip-data depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

  Package lsb-release is not configured yet.
 python3-distro depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip-data:
 hplip-data depends on python3-distro; however:
  Package python3-distro is not configured yet.
 hplip-data depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package hplip-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-all:
 python3-all depends on python3 (= 3.10.6-1~22.04); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-all depends on python3-distutils (>= 3.10.6-1~); however:
  Package python3-distutils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 systemd
 python3-wheel
 python3-dev
 python3-pip
 lsb-release
 python3-lib2to3
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-distutils
 python3-setuptools
 python3-distro
 hplip-data
 python3-all
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output is the same for `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. Some time ago, I updated the python symlinks in /usr/bin to point to python3.11 instead of python3.10. It seemed to work without issues, but maybe that can cause problems like this? I have since attempted to reinstall both versions which replaced the symlinks.

Here are the problematic packages from `dpkg -l`:

```
iF  python3                     3.10.6-1~22.04                          amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 ver>
iU  python3-all                 3.10.6-1~22.04                          amd64        package depending on all supported Python 3 runtime versions
iU  python3-dev                 3.10.6-1~22.04                          amd64        header files and a static library for Python (default)
iU  python3-distro              1.7.0-1                                 all          Linux OS platform information API
iU  python3-distutils           3.10.6-1~22.04                          all          distutils package for Python 3.x
iU  python3-lib2to3             3.10.6-1~22.04                          all          Interactive high-level object-oriented language (lib2to3)
ii  python3-minimal             3.10.6-1~22.04                          amd64        minimal subset of the Python language (default python3 version)
iU  python3-pip                 22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3                  all          Python package installer
iU  python3-pkg-resources       59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1               all          Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources
iU  python3-setuptools          59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1               all          Python3 Distutils Enhancements
iU  python3-wheel               0.37.1-2ubuntu0.22.04.1                 all          built-package format for Python
```

Additionally, systemd also shows up as "iF" for some reason. When I tried `sudo dpkg --configure python3`:

```
Setting up python3 (3.10.6-1~22.04) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
dpkg-query: package 'ibus-table' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus-table
error running python rtupdate hook ibus-table
dpkg-query: package 'ibus' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus
error running python rtupdate hook ibus
dpkg-query: package 'python3-uno' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of python3-uno
error running python rtupdate hook python3-uno
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer-common
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer-common
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
```

The output is similar for `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. I noticed "ibus-table" wasn't installed, so I tried that, resulting in a similar errors to the first output. I believe doing this also caused systemd to show as "iF" in the dpkg list.

I also tried forcefully removing with `sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends python3` and reinstalling. Everything has resulted similar errors. I'm running versin 22.04.2.

**EDIT**: I think I was able to fix some of the packages by deleting `/etc/resolv.conf` and then running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. The only package with dependency errors now is python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved this by installing these packages:

`sudo apt install python3-uno system-config-printer-common system-config-printer`

and then running:

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

I'm not sure if or why these ones specifically caused the issue, but it ended up resolving the issue at least for now.

Comment: Like, apparently, every single solution on Stack Exchange for this kind of error, not a single thing on this page works, only creates the same errors it's supposed to fix, or unexplained new errors which, when I google for solutions, the "solutions" don't work, they just create yet another round of explained new errors, all "solutions" to which just generate still another round of unexplained errors, which I google for, but the "solutions" only generate yet another round of unexplained errors, so I google for solutions to them, but all solutions online only give unexplained new errors...